# conda 'ResolvePackageNotFound' error although I installed all the files in the same path

Tags: bioinformatics

When attempting to create a conda environment I get a `ResolvePackageNotFound` error.

```
(base) C:\Users\dell\docking_py> conda env create -f .conda.yml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
 - autodock
 - mgltools
 - autodock-vina
```

I've installed `autodock`, `autodock-vina` and `mgltools` in `docking_py` itself.

[image: Screenshot of anaconda prompt]

Answer (score 1):

All three packages: `autodock`, `autodock-vina`, and `mgltools` appear to be available on the [Bioconda](https://bioconda.github.io/) channel.

It looks like you need to specify the channel that you are using:

```yaml
name: my_env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - autodock
  - mgltools
  - autodock-vina
```

Including any other dependencies that you have.

However, note that Bioconda does not support Windows, so consider alternatives such as WSL2 or Docker, with a Miniforge variant for Conda.

Comment: The bioconda channel only works for Mac and Linux mine is a windows PC. Can you give any other alternative please?

Comment: If they aren't available for install on windows using conda you'll need to use windows subsystem linux or remove them from your environment and specify them elsewhere.